# Create new PowerPoint presentation from PowerPoint template using VBA in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, templates, powerpoint

I have an Excel macro that opens a PowerPoint file from a specified location. The PowerPoint file is a template.

I need to create a new presentation based on the template design.

My code will open the template rather than a new presentation based on that template:

```vb
Sub Open_PowerPoint_Presentation()
    'Opens a PowerPoint Document from Excel
    
    Dim objPPT As Object
    
    Set objPPT = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
    objPPT.Visible = True
    
    'Change the directory path and file name to the location
    'of your document
    
    objPPT.Presentations.Open "C:\Users\Colin\Documents\Custom Office Templates\PowerPoint Templates\Edge45 Monthly Report Template Macro.potm"
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my opinion, you should open your template file with the `Untitled` parameter (`Open` method) set to true.

```
objPPT.Presentations.Open FileName:="MyTemplate Macro.potm", Untitled:=msoTrue
```

According to [Presentations.Open Method (PowerPoint)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff746171.aspx),

> Opens the file without a title. This is equivalent to creating a copy
>   of the file.